# g++ No such file or directory sublime text

Tags: c++, compilation, build-process, sublimetext2

Trying to compile hello world on windows 8, using Sublime Text 2, get the following error:

```
g++: : No such file or directory
g++: No input files
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let me know if there's any other info you need in order to solve the problem. It's just as simple as that, it doesn't compile.

Comment: You tried to run GCC, but GCC isn't installed.

Comment: That was actually after installing gcc. Problem was that the file i was working on wasn't saved. Thanks for the comment @jogojapan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, but embarrassing to post. The issue was that I assumed that Sublime Text 2 autosaved upon quitting the program. SB2 auto-opens the last file you're working on, so I thought it was already saved. Saving the file to whatever path eliminates the error and compiles fine.